# Google Cloud SQL locks me out, access denied, a few minutes after launch

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying out Google Cloud SQL for the first time. Initially I am able to connect and use the database normally, but after a little while the instance seems to "forget" both my root password and another user I create, and resetting the root password doesn't work.

**Method**

I create a D0 instance, get an IP address, add network access for my home IP address, and set the root password. I also check "Only allow SSL connections." Then I log in as root using the mysql client (command line) and it connects as you would expect. I create a database and another user, as well as a variety of tables and some initial inserts. I close the root session and reconnect with the new user as well, and then I do some selects to make sure the new user can connect and access the tables. I go away and do something else for a few minutes. When I come back, I get the same error for both users (root and the new one I created):

`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'my.home.ip.address' (using password: YES)`

Nothing has changed. My IP address is the same (of course, because I'm able to make a TCP connection to MySQL).

**Get This**

Changing the root password via the Developers Console has no effect! I'm locked out of this instance and can't get back in.

When this happened the first time, I thought I must have done something wrong, so I deleted the whole D0 instance and started over. Same experience the second time. Again, changing the root password using the console has no effect. Unchecking "Only allow SSL connections" also has no effect.

Why is this instance locking me out?

Comment: When you get the "Access denied" are you trying to connect using SSL certs? For the "Only allow SSL connections" to have effect you have to restart the instance.

Comment: I imagine you've authorized "your IP" but depending on your ISP are you **sure** the IP is always the same?  Check e.g via http://whatismyipaddress.com/ -- is the IPv4 address that shows up there exactly the one you've authorized on your Cloud SQL instance...?

Comment: @RazvanMusaloiu-E. Yes, I've tried restarting with and without "Only allows SSL connections"

Comment: @AlexMartelli Yeah, I'm certain that it's my real IP, and it's further confirmed by two things: 1. my successful connections to this instance before it suddenly stopped working, and 2. if I couldn't open a TCP connection, I would not get an "Access denied" error; I'd get a connection failure.

Comment: I tried using SSL certs as well as password auth specifying `mysql --ssl ...`. My understanding of "Only allow SSL connections" is that it will allow connections via `mysql --ssl ...` and that using a client cert is optional, but to be sure I tried it both ways.

Comment: "Only allow SSL connection" means you MUST use --ssl to connect. Normal connection will get access deny error. Besides, you still need to supply the password.

Comment: @Tianzhou Yes, that's how I was able to connect successfully at first (though the client will fall back to non-ssl, so it's hard to tell whether those connections were really encrypted) and I use the same flags -- the same entire command line -- after it stops accepting connections. I think something else is wrong.

Comment: Could you post your project ID so I can open a case in Google Cloud Support on your behalf?  Thanks in advance.